# Centered Updownarrow after By Lemma 7?

Tags: center

How can we center the Updownarrow right after By Lemma 7?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

By Lemma 7:  \begin{center}\(\Updownarrow\)\end{center}

By Lemma 7:  \[\Updownarrow\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Centred with respect to the text area or centred with respect to the remaining space in the line?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The arrows in a line By Lemma 7:  \begin{center}\(\Updownarrow\)\end{center} and a line  \[\Updownarrow\] should align. Perhaps that is the same as being centred with respect to the text area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities for indented and unindented lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{By Lemma 7:}\hfil$\Updownarrow$

\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\indent By Lemma 7:}\hfil$\Updownarrow$

By Lemma 7:  \[\Updownarrow\]

\end{document}
```

[image]