# Centering only a part of a line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

I would like to center only a part of line.

It would be a command `\centerOnly` that could be used as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3cm]
\item One has \centerOnly{$x=2$}. 
\item Furthermore, one has
\[
x^2 = 4.
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The expected result would be
[image]

This command should also work within `enumerate` and `itemize` environments and should center its argument with respect with the "box" of the environment.

Do you how to achieve this.

---

Here is a picture of the real document where I want to use such a feature:

[image]

---

Edit: the solution

```
\newcommand{\centerOnly}[1]{\mbox{}\hfill#1\hfill\mbox{}}
```

gives the following output:

[image]

It's an interesting idea but it does not exactly do what I want : it centers the argument in the remaining space instead of centering it the whole "box" of the environment.

The text "A inversible <=> det(A)" should be more on the left, exactly above the other centered formula.

Comment: Maybe you could use this quick and dirty hack: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688720/centered-updownarrow-after-by-lemma-7/688723#688723

Comment: So far, it is working. You can make it answer if you want.

Comment: Great to hear it is working for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the same quick and dirty hack as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688723/36296

The basic idea is to hide the width of the text prior to the equation with a `\makebox` of zero width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3cm]
\item\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{One has}\hfil$x=2$. 
\item Furthermore, one has
\[
x^2 = 4.
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you expected, but just try the below, whether it meets the requirement?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\centerOnly}[1]{\hfill#1\hfill}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3cm]
\item One has \centerOnly{$x=2$}. 
\item Furthermore, one has
\[
x^2 = 4.
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea but it does not exactly do what I want : it centers the argument in the remaining space instead of centering it the whole "box" of the environment. See the edit of the question.